# Asp.net MVC Oracle database connection with DBContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I have application build on ASP.NET mvc. This application connects to Oracle database where data is located.

My code for adding DBContext to services:

```
services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(_ => new ApplicationDbContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")) );
```

If user leave web application page on browser without  any action for example for 20 minutes  Then error occurs 
"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
This error relates to database oracle connection.

Can you suggest anything to resolve this error?

Comment: did you resolve this issue??

Comment: Yes i have sold it. It was in configuration in IIS. IT was closing or going to sleep if no any request sending to host more than 15 minutes. I have just set it to 0 and it never goes sleep.